# Shell script to extract running sid

Tags: shell, unix

I have a requirement to fetch the current SID of running Oracle instance, I know a keyword which will be part of SID, how can i fetch and assign it to variable.

I am trying something

```
ps -ef | grep pmon | grep TESTDB    
oracle    5527 23570  0 05:03 pts/5    00:00:00 /bin/ksh -c ps -ef | grep pmon | grep TESTDB    
oracle   26617     1  0 Sep24 ?        01:10:57 ora_pmon_TESTDB02
```

From above how do i extract just TESTDB02

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want:

```
ps -e -o cmd | grep '^ora_pmon_TESTDB' | sed 's/^ora_pmon_//'
```

- `ps -e -o cmd` prints commands of all processes
- then I grep only processes that start with 'ora_pmon_TESTDB'
- then I remove the ora_pmon_ string from the beginning of the line using sed
- I will be left with TESTDB02

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to get n-th field:

`[here goes your chain of commands] | awk -r '{print $8;}' | awk -F '_' -r '{print $(NF);}'`

Explanation:

- Your chain of commands finds information but it is not well formated
- `awk -r '{print $8;}'` prints only 8th field  which is `ora_pmon_TESTDB02`
- `awk -F '_' -r '{print $(NF);}'` is using `_` as field separator (`-F` option), and prints last field which is `TESTDB02`

Answer (score 0):

Find the running Oracle instance and then cut the Oracle SID from pmon process.

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep pmon | awk '{print $9}' | awk -F"_" '{idx=length($0)-length($NF);sid=substr($0,idx+1,length($0));print sid}'
```